# Does convergence in measure imply $L^1$ convergence (finite measure)?

Tags: real-analysis

The course text I am working with is Gerald Folland's *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*. Below is a proof I have drafted up on a fact I'm unsure whether is true. If anybody could look over what I've written (or maybe explain why the statement I'm trying to prove isn't true), I would appreciate it very much!

---

Let $f_n\to f$ in measure over finite measure space $(X,M,\mu)$. Then for all $\epsilon,\delta>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\mu(\{x:|f-f_n|\geq\epsilon\})<\delta$ for all $n>N$. Denote $E=\{x:|f-f_n|\geq\epsilon\}^c=\{x:|f-f_n|<\epsilon\}$. It follows that: $$\int_E |f-f_n|\leq\epsilon\int_E=\epsilon\mu(E).$$Since $\mu(E)\leq\mu(X)<\infty$, we conclude for all $\epsilon_0=\epsilon\mu(E)>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\int|f_n-f|<\epsilon_0$ for all $n>N$ (i.e., $f\to f_n$ in $L^1$).

Comment: Let $X=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure and $f_n=n^2\chi_{[0,n^{-1}]}$. Then $f_n\to 0$ in measure and $\int\lvert f_n\rvert\,d\mu\to\infty$.

Comment: Good answer! Thanks again.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio Actually, I just noticed something: shouldn't the integral be finite? It would still disprove my initial claim, but just making sure whether I'm making an error.

Comment: $f_n=n1_{(0,\frac  1n)}, f=0$.

Comment: @JAG131 The integral of what?

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio The integral you gave: $\int|f_n|d\mu$. And I should again warn, this is still very new material to me. I could be entirely wrong, but my understanding is that this integral should be finite seeing that the function is bounded and has a domain which is restricted to a compact interval.

Comment: @JAG131 By $\chi_A$ I mean the function $\chi_A(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\in A\\ 0&\text{if }x\notin A\end{cases}$, therefore $\int\lvert f_n\rvert\,d\mu=n$.